# Логика работы функции srand ()

Tags: c

Пытаюсь разобраться в генерации псевдослучайных чисел в СИ.

Верно ли я понимаю, что функция `srand (seed)` устанавливает начальную точку для генерации
множества псевдослучайных целых чисел, а генерирует в свою очередь непосредственно функция `rand ()` и в качестве аргумента `seed` для
переустановки генератора используется любое число?

Вопрос образовался когда я увидел, что при одинаковом значении аргумента `seed`, числа, получаемое из функции `rand ()` будут равны.

Пример, в котором первые три числа всегда будут равны:

```
int main(void) {
  srand(4);
  printf("%d\n", 80 + rand()%21);
  srand(4);
  printf("%d\n", 80 + rand()%21);
  srand(4);
  printf("%d\n", 80 + rand()%21);
  srand(1);
  printf("%d\n", 80 + rand()%21);
  srand(0);
  printf("%d\n", 80 + rand()%21);
}
```

Comment: Да, верно......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Верно ли я понимаю, что функция `srand (seed)` устанавливает начальную точку для генерации множества псевдослучайных целых чисел, а генерирует в свою очередь непосредственно функция `rand ()` и в качестве аргумента `seed` для переустановки генератора используется любое число?

Да, верно.

При этом спецификация языка гарантирует, что до первого вызова `srand` функция `rand` ведет себя как после `srand(1)`. То есть вот в таком случае

```
int main(void) {
  printf("%d\n", 80 + rand()%21);
  srand(1);
  printf("%d\n", 80 + rand()%21);
}
```

числа тоже будут равны.